# How to fix "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'" when trying to apply a random rotation to a bullet?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a shotgun in my 2D game on unity but I cannot get the shotgun spread correct and I keep getting the error error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and tutorials aren't helping

```
void shoot()
{


    GameObject BulletIns = Instantiate(Bullet, ShootPoint.position, ShootPoint.rotation);
    BulletIns.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(BulletIns.transform.right * BulletSpeed);
    BulletIns.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(BulletIns.transform.Rotate(Range(-10, 10), Range(-10, 10), 0));
    gunAnimator.SetTrigger("Shoot");
    Destroy(BulletIns, 1);

}
```

I want the shotgun to shoot a bullet that goes straight and I also want the shotgun to shoot another bullet at a random angle but I keep getting an error with my code.

Comment: Check documentation if given method returns value...

Comment: you are passing in Transform.rotate to addforce. 
 Transform.rotate has a method signature of void. 
 You cannot pass that in to add force. 
 
 you need to get the  Transform.rotation

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the rigidbody rotation

```
var rotation = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
BulletIns.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().SetRotation(rotation);
```